# Alexa Smart Home controll with RPi - but Endpoint problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have a problem (what else) :-)

I just got a Alexa Dot and want to control my 'smart home' with it. The 'smart home' exists already and is a DIY solution, controlled by a Raspberry Pi. The Pi is in a local network.

Problem 1 is that the Router and/or internet provider does not allow port forwarding (at least I could not get it running yet). (Germany: Speedport LTE 2 with O2 Free M Flex mobile internet LTE/UMTS)
So I can't send messages from the internet to my RPi. Means also Amazon AWS can't.
I wanted to do it with DynDNS... but useless if I can't make a port forwarding to the Pi.

That doesn't give me much options, I guess.

Option 1 would be to set an endpoint on my webserver and save the result from Alexa there. Then send a request from the Pi to the webserver and check if there are new 'actions' to do. But it wouldn't be in 'real time' anymore. Can't send a request every second. Poor Server.

Option 2 (in my mind)... It is possible to install Amazon AWS on the RPi. Would it me possible that the Alexa Dot is taking my voice command (the hardware is good for that), the Amazon Server is processing it BUT is not sending the 'action' back to the dot, instead to the RPi?

Is there any other option? I wasn't digging too deep yet into the subject of creating own Alexa Skills and the processing. Maybe there is an other way.

What I need at the end are custom Alexa skills to control my smart home. Like 'Switch the light on'... and the request has to end up at the RPi, which is then processing this 'command'. So, I need the 'command' somewho delivered to the RPi in my local network.

I would be very thankful for any working solution. 
Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you can't purchase a static IP for your home? that would be easiest. Alternatively, you could setup your webserver to receive data from the alexa skill. Then have your rpi poll the webserver (once every 10 seconds is not so bad).

Comment: Yes, static IP is a dream. I can't even get a public IP. Due to the fact that it's a mobile internet connection, I get only a private IP. :-( No chance to get even a public one.
Yes, I had that idea as well. But either I have a delay of x seconds ("Alexa, switch the light on"... 10 seconds ... light on. Not so great if its dark and you need to go urgently to the restroom ;-) ). Or I have to check it every second. So every 1-2 seconds a request to the server. Also not really great.